# Error while installing pygame 1.9.2 for Python 3.4 (OS X)

Tags: macos, pygame, pip, python-3.4

I was wondering why does the installation of Pygame 1.9.2 for Python 3.4 fail to work (Procedure at http://pygame.org/wiki/macintosh).
When I try to run the pip command to install pygame (last step), the following error shows up:

```
# pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
# doing the installation stuff successfully for the first part
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -c src/cdrom.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.5/src/cdrom.o
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.5/src/cdrom.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -lSDLmain -lSDL -o build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.5/pygame/cdrom.cpython-35m-darwin.so -Wl,-framework,Cocoa
    building 'pygame.color' extension
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ddarwin -D_THREAD_SAFE -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -c src/color.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.5/src/color.o
    src/color.c:316:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Py_TPFLAGS_CHECKTYPES'
        COLOR_TPFLAGS,
        ^
    src/color.c:276:23: note: expanded from macro 'COLOR_TPFLAGS'
    #define COLOR_TPFLAGS COLOR_TPFLAGS_COMMON
                          ^
    src/color.c:272:49: note: expanded from macro 'COLOR_TPFLAGS_COMMON'
        (Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE | Py_TPFLAGS_CHECKTYPES)
                                                    ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/var/folders/yj/c9jf0d390yn3lnqrpz8489fr0000gn/T/pip-s2tg3zc8-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/yj/c9jf0d390yn3lnqrpz8489fr0000gn/T/pip-we1hfsvl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/yj/c9jf0d390yn3lnqrpz8489fr0000gn/T/pip-s2tg3zc8-build
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error just now. I pointed to the commit before the last revision to get it working for now.

```
pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/@96203be
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! It worked perfectly.